# Just bought four BERU Glow Plugs. But they seem to have been used?

Tags: glowplugs

[image]

Is the color of the heated part normal for 4 glow plugs that are brand new ... ?

Comment: I would assume they are tested before shipment. This would cause the colorization on the tip.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought, but I wasn't sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, depending on the specific glow plug, this coloring is normal.

Here is a link to a new BERU plug that has the same coloring in the image:

http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/sku/Beru/Glow_Plug/W0133-1631189.html

Here is a nice shot of a used glow plug:

[image: used plug]

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you decide to 'test' your new glow plugs.

The lot of glow plugs start off with 12 volts, but then after 2 seconds the voltage is dropped by their ECU to 4 volts operating voltage. If you keep a supply of 12 volts to the glow plug they will burn out and become useless.